# Lock timeout when dropping table after having dropped column

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net, sql-server-ce

I spare you from code details. Basically I run several SQL queries on a **SQL CE** database within a ado.net **transaction**, i.e.

```
ALTER TABLE [FIRST] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_FIRST_SECOND]

ALTER TABLE [FIRST] DROP COLUMN [FK2SECOND]            

DROP TABLE [SECOND]
```

In words

> 1. I remove the foreign key constraint related to [FK2SECOND]
> 2. I remove [FK2SECOND]
> 3. I remove table [SECOND], i.e. the one which had been
>      referenced.

My transaction will fail at (3) with a lock timeout, saying:

> SQL Server Compact timed out waiting for a lock. The default lock time
>   is 2000ms for devices and 5000ms for desktops. The default lock
>   timeout can be increased in the connection string using the ssce:
>   default lock timeout property.

Separating the DROP TABLE from the rest by taking this query out of the transaction works.

FMO that lock is a generic problem, which could/should not be healed by increasing the default lock time. What would instead be best practice to cope with this (table) locking?

Comment: How do you know it fails at 3? Try skipping step 2 (you can do that later)

Comment: Actually "fails at (3)" means, I debugged and ran into timeout behavior at this point.